# Get script content

Tags: javascript

Consider the following:

```
<head>
    <script src="somejsfile.js"></script>
    <script>
        var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        firstScript.innerScript = firstScript.innerScript.replace("foo","test");
    </script>
</head>
```

somejsfile.js:

```
console.log("foo");
```

Now, this (pseudo)code is for illustration only; it does not work, because there is no `innerScript` element. So, is there a way to get/manipulate `console.log("foo");` using JavaScript DOM manipulation, in a similar way to `iframe.innerDocument`?

(EDIT: If you would like to know what I need it for:

I am trying to debug whether the script file is loaded or a 404 is occurring. My script contains console.log in the first line, and that line is not executed inside my WP8 xap cordova application.)

Comment: try innerHTML this will work.

Comment: Dear deduplicators, thanks for pointing to an answer that is older than the ECMA6 and ECMA5 standard. So may I assume that nothing has changed in the new versions?

Comment: yes i think so. or you can you Text.